# Why is this true: The only orthogonal projection that is also unitary from $\Bbb C^n$ to $\Bbb C^n$ is the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

Can anyone explain me please how to see this statement: the only orthogonal projection that is also unitary from $\Bbb C^n$ to $\Bbb C^n$ is the Identity. 
how can I prove formally that? or how can I see that only the Identity satisfy it?

Comment: As the answers below make clear, you can prove this using just algebra. But, conceptually speaking, you should realize that an orthogonal projection $P$ is completely determined by its range $M$, the subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ that $P$ projects onto. Since untitaries are, in particular, invertible linear transformations, they are all onto i.e. have range $\mathbb{C}^n$. So, if an orthogonal projection is also unitary, it is just projection onto $\mathbb{C}^n$ i.e. is the identity map.

Comment: More generally: in a unital ring, the only invertible idempotent is the identity. The adjoint is just a distraction here.

Answer (score 5):

Unitary means that 
$$
P^*P=PP^*=I.
$$
Projection means that
$$
P^2=P.
$$
Combination of the two implies that
$$
P(P^*P)=P(PP^*) \Longrightarrow PP^*P=P^2P^*\Longrightarrow I\cdot P=PP^*\Longrightarrow P=I.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}$
$$
P=P^2=P^*P=1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$P\;\;\text{is an orthogonal projection}\;\iff P=P^*\;,\;\;P^2=P$$

$$P\;\;\text{is a unitary operator}\;\iff PP^*=I$$

So it must be that $\;P=\;$ ...

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks, @user1551